# C# Form X Button Clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I find out if a form is closed by clicking the X button or by (this.Close())?

Comment: This one is more simpler than writing code for it.

Answer (score 23):

the form has the event **FormClosing** with parameter of type *FormClosingEventArgs*.

```
// catch the form closing event
private void Form1_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e )
{
    // check the reason (UserClosing)
    if ( e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing )
    {
        // do stuff like asking user
        if ( MessageBox.Show( this,
                 "Are you sure you want to close the form?",
                 "Closing Form",
                 MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                 MessageBoxIcon.Question ) == DialogResult.Cancel )
         {
             // cancel the form closing if necessary
             e.Cancel = true;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to ask if Really Close. My Form has a Cancel button and at clicking Cancel I set to null a field that will be returned. From outside, I know that I don't have to do something when this form returns null. But when the form is closed by clicking X, the field is not null so the outside code crashes.

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the 'X' altogether?

One of the properties of the form is "ControlBox" just set this to `false`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the returned field to null, like you do when you click Cancel in your Form:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing )
    {
        returnfield = null;
        this.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `OnFormClosing` the `FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason` is `UserClosing`either to 'X' button or `form.Close()` method.
My solution:

```
//override the OnFormClosing event
        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)// the reason that you need
                base.OnFormClosing(e);
            else e.Cancel = true; // cancel if the close reason is not the expected one
        }
//create a new method that allows to handle the close reasons
        public void closeForm(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) this.Close();
            else e.Cancel = true;
        }

  //if you want to close the form or deny the X button action invoke closeForm method
    myForm.closeForm(new FormClosingEventArgs(CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall, false));
                              //the reason that you want ↑
```

In this example the close (X) button does not close the form