# Method for "After" button click

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, methods

i have a winform, on which i want to apply a method after the X button is pressed,
the Problem is, winform only gives you the following Options, FormClosing or FormClosed

```
private void MailNamen_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
        //Or
        private void MailNamen_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Is there i way i can let it do something, when the User Actually Clicks on it, as opposed to leting it cover the cases when the form Closes without a User Click on the X????
thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: Use the formclosedeventargs, I can't remember syntax but I'm sure somethin on that says how it closed

Comment: Are you asking this because you want to stop the form from closing on certain instances ?

Comment: @inisheer, I've read the question as the OP wishes to do something different if closed by X

Comment: Look at this link I think he answered your question

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3735824/1546137

Comment: @Sayse Correct. I misread your comment. Unfortunately, those event args only allow you to see if the form was closed under very general circumstances. None specific to the X button.

Answer (score 1):

The [`FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) property tells you why the form is being closed. If you look at the [`CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx) enum, one of the values is `UserClosing` - this happens when the user presses the `X` button or presses Alt+F4.

The `FormClosing` event happens after the user clicks the `X` button but before the form is actually closed - you can still cancel closing the form at this point.

**Edit:**
If you *specifically* want to handle the `X` button, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9445682/682404 - this shows how to detect click events in the non-client area of a window and determine if the close button was clicked.

As that answer says, you *really, really* need a *specific* reason to do this, otherwise you'll confuse users.

Comment: Unfortunately, CloseReason.UserClosing is also used if you right-click and close the application in the task bar. Therefore, it doesn't work only for the 'X' button.

Comment: @Inisheer That's because there are more than one way to close a form. A program shouldn't differentiate between those ways because it'd confuse users. The purpose of the `X` button is to close the form so it makes sense to handle all user-initiated form closing events the same way. This is why there's no specific _X was clicked_ event.

Comment: Correct, but the OP specifically states he/she wants to know about the X button. Whether it's possible has yet to be answered.

Comment: @Inisheer You're right, I edited my answer for that. It's still a pretty bad idea to handle the `X` button differently from other ways of closing the form.